# Eliminating the parameter??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, parametric

I have the problem

$\ x=2^t+2^{-t} ,y=2^t-2^{-t}$

Do I need to use a logarithm to solve this equation? If anyone can help me solve for the parameter I would greatly appreciate it. If this helps, it graphs as a horizontal parabola. Thank you!

Comment: The question is totally unclear as it stands: are you trying to draw a curve from the given parametric form or something else?

Comment: Is the last term supposed to be $2^{-t}$ instead of $2^{-2}$?

Comment: Assuming that the last term in $y$ is $2^{-t}$, the curve is not a "horizontal parabola" but a hyperbola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2-y^2=(4^t+4^{-t}+2)-(4^t+4^{-t}-2)=4$$
Hence equation of curve : $x^2-y^2=4$

Comment: @dxiv thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You can just define $z=2^t$ and rewrite the equations using that for whatever purpose you have.  Then when you are done, $t=\log_2 z$, but you don't have to carry the powers along.  You have two equations in three unknowns, so will have an infinite set of solutions.  If (as I guess) the last term is supposed to be $2^{-t}$ you can just add and subtract the equations and things are simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$x=2^t+\frac{1}{2^t}$$

and

$$ 2^t=y+\frac{1}{4}$$

thus

$$x=(y+\frac{1}{4})+(\frac{1}{y+\frac{1}{4}})$$

$$=\frac{16y^2+8y+17}{16y+4}$$